# C# MVC View can't find POCO reference in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, poco

I am making a C# MVC project.

One of my view has to loop a list of item. The type of those items is a POCO, created inside my Logic project.

Everything goes well until the view starts loading. I get this error:

> CS0012: The type 'Note' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Logique, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The assembly Logique should be Logic, but, for some reasons, the compiler calls it Logique.

P.S. Looping with Razor.

POCO:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class Note
{
    [DataMember]
    public string NoteName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

The problem was: I was referencing a POCO in a .Exe project. I had to make it Class Library.

Project->Properties->Application->Output type->Class library